# Ansible: Custom fact (set_facts) is undefined when accessing it using hostvars in tasks running in other host

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to configure a Docker swarm cluster with Ansible, When the manager node is provisioned I set a custom fact (docker_manager_address) with the ip address, so the other nodes can know the ip to join the swarm.

The fact is set correctly and I can get its value in the manager node, but when I try to get the fact in tasks that are run in other nodes (using hostvars), it´s not defined.

Here are my tasks:

```yaml
- name: Declare the address of the first Swarm manager as a fact.
  set_fact:
    docker_manager_address: "{{ docker_swarm_addr }}:{{ docker_swarm_port }}"
  when: "inventory_hostname == groups['docker_swarm_managers'][0]"

- name: Print manager address
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: hostvars[groups['docker_swarm_managers'][0]]['docker_manager_address']

- name: Distribute the fact containing address of the first Swarm manager.
  set_fact:
    docker_manager_address: "{{ hostvars[groups['docker_swarm_managers'][0]]['docker_manager_address'] }}"
  when: "inventory_hostname != groups['docker_swarm_managers'][0]"
```

The "Print manager address" works when it´s executed in the node which sets the fact, but on the worker nodes it´s empty.

My playbook it´s just this for now:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Update system packages
      apt: update_cache=yes force_apt_get=yes cache_valid_time=3600
      become: true

  roles:
    - users
    - ssh
    - { role: geerlingguy.docker, become: true }
    - docker-swarm
```

The swarm setup code is adapted from this role: https://github.com/atosatto/ansible-dockerswarm, which uses this strategy. Not sure why it´s not working for me.

Using Ansible 2.9,

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I was using Vagrant to test my playbooks and by default it uses "limit" to specify which hosts to run. Changing to "all" solved the issue.